# NoSuchFieldError: Companion for azure.application-insights

Tags: spring-boot, azure-web-app-service, spring-cloud, azure-java-sdk, spring-cloud-azure

Currently migrating my spring-boot app to use the latest compatibile version for JDK 8. I'm currently receiving this error when running the spring-boot-app

```
ightsTelemetryAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'azure.application-insights-com.microsoft.applicationinsights.boot.ApplicationInsightsProperties': Initialization
 of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Companion
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:165)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:175)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:155)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:97)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5218)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1016)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1903)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webRequestTrackingFilterRegistrationBean' defined in class path resource [com/microsoft/applicationinsights/boot/ApplicationInsightsWebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
'webRequestTrackingFilterRegistrationBean' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.microsoft.applicationinsights.boot.ApplicationInsightsTelemetryAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor paramet
er 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'azure.application-insights-com.microsoft.applicationinsights.boot.ApplicationInsightsProperties': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Companion
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
```

I have these versions for my applicationinsights, spring-boot-starter-parent 2.7.12, spring-cloud-dependencies 2021.0.3 and spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap in my parent pom. I updated to the latest version of applicationinsights but I'm still receiving the same error.

```
           <dependency>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>applicationinsights-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>applicationinsights-logging-logback</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.4</version>
            </dependency>
```

I've updated the following artifacts and I've also added spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap dependency

| artifact | previous version | updated version |
| --- | --- | --- |
| spring-boot-starter-parent | 2.2.4.RELEASE | 2.7.12 |
| spring-cloud-dependencies | Finchley.M9 | 2021.0.3 |
| applicationinsights-spring-boot-starter | 1.0.0-BETA | 2.6.4 |
| application-insights-logging | 2.1.1 | 2.6.4 |

Comment: I'm sure there's still a version mismatch there. When I go to https://start.spring.io and select boot 2.7 I get `com.azure.spring:spring-cloud-azure-dependencies:4.9.0`

Comment: Based on this matrix its using the correct dependency version
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/wiki/Spring-Versions-Mapping

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be occurring due to the initialization of the `azure.application-insights-com.microsoft.applicationinsights.boot.ApplicationInsightsProperties` bean (or) due to the version incompatibility between Azure Application Insights package and Spring Boot you are using.

Try upgrading/ downgrading the *Azure Application Insights library version* which is compatible with your *Spring Boot version*.

(Or)

***create your application with Spring Boot 2.7.x version to use `ApplicationInsights` package 2.6.4 version.***

Run `mvn clean install` once you upgrade the versions.

[image]

**Alternatives:**

- AFAIK,`applicationinsights-spring-boot-starter` package is for old way of configuring Application Insights.
- Instead you can use Java Agent/ `applicationinsights-runtime-attach` in your application to configure AppInsights.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>applicationinsights-runtime-attach</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.14</version>
</dependency>
```

**pom.xml:**

```xml
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>applicationinsights-runtime-attach</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.14</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Create `applicationinsights-dev.json` under `src>main>resources` folder and add :

```json
{
"connectionString":"InstrumentationKey=XXXXX;IngestionEndpoint=https://XXXXXX.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://XXXXX.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/"
}
```

Add below configuration in `applications.properties`:

```json
-Dapplicationinsights:
runtime-attach:
configuration:
classpath:
file: "applicationinsights-dev.json"
```

**main()**

```java
package  com.javabycode.springboot;
import  com.microsoft.applicationinsights.attach.ApplicationInsights;
import  org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public  class  MyWebApplication{

public  static  void  main(String[] args) throws  Exception {

ApplicationInsights.attach();

SpringApplication.run(MyWebApplication.class, args);

}

}
```

**References:**

[Upgrading from 2.x - Azure Monitor Application Insights Java - Azure Monitor | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-standalone-upgrade-from-2x)
[Configure Azure Monitor Application Insights for Spring Boot - Azure Monitor | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-spring-boot)